# How is it possible for bson to be imported without the pymongo namespace?

Tags: python, pymongo, pypi

The Pypi entry for pymongo entry states[1]

> The bson package is an implementation of the BSON format for Python

and

> Do not install the “bson” package. PyMongo comes with its own bson package; doing “easy_install bson” installs a third-party package that is incompatible with PyMongo.

But the pymongo API documentation[2] shows examples of `bson` being imported without a `pymongo` prefix / namespace like so:

```
import bson
```

How is it possible for bson to be imported without the pymongo namespace?

I would have expected the import statement to be `import pymongo.bson` because the referenced bson implementation came with pymongo.

[1] https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo/

[2] http://api.mongodb.org/python/3.0.3/api/bson/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because pymongo setup installs the `bson` package it provides the same way it installs the `pymongo` package it also provides.

Look at github where you can see the two modules: `pymongo` and `bson`: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver

The `setup.py` file defines:

```
"packages": ["bson", "pymongo", "gridfs"]
```

So these are the packages installed in your python `site-packages/` dir